# Setting multiple static directories on Express

Tags: node.js, express, view, static

In my Node.js project I'm trying to set multiple folders as static folder by using `app.use`.

My project consists of many Node.js projects that communicates with each other. The folder structure looks like this:

```
--app.js
--assets
--project1
    -----views
            ---project1.js
            ---project1.html
--projects2
    -----views
            ---project2.js
            ---project2.html
etc.
```

I need the `views` and the `assets` folders to be static. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple `express.static`

You can have multiple static folders. Use directories relative to `app.js`. For example:

```
var app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/../../views'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/../../assets/views'));
```

Comment: It doesn't recognise any of them.. I used this path: __dirname+ './assets'

Comment: Remember that __dirname is the path to the base of your project.